# How to remove non-specific char of a string/dataframe[i] in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, function, data-cleaning

in my data cleaning process i found some strings with inhbit a single char that might bias my analysis

i.e. 'hello please help r me with this s question'.

Until now i only found tools to remove specific chars , like

```
char= 's'
def char_remover(text: 
    spec_char = ''.join (i for i in text if i not in s text)
    return spec_char
```

or the rsplit(), split() functions, which are good for deleting first /last char of a string.

In the end, I want to code a function that removes all single chars (whitespace char whitespace) from my string/dataframe.

My own thoughts on that question:

```
def spec_char_remover(text):
    spec_char_rem= ''.join(i for i in text if i not len(i) <= 1) 
    return spec_char_rem
```

But that obviously didn´t work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add two  sample lines and their expected (cleaned) output please? I am not understanding clearly the logic beind the cleaning, sorry.

Comment: , thanks for your fast reply, if i get your quesiton right,  string=' please help r me with this s quesition'       cleaned_string=  'please help me with this question'                                                           I apllied some algoriths like tf and tfidf, and some of the most "frequent" words are single chars, therefore they bias my further analysis.

Comment: Yeah, Moosefeather's answer should be good :)

Comment: ill try that asap, thank you

Comment: You should be careful with some particular cases such as "I" and possible slangs, but other than that it should be fine for the most part.

Comment: since i use very techincals patents, pronouns and slangs aren´t a problem. But thanks for that tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'hello please help r me with this s question'
>>> re.sub(' . ', ' ', s)
'hello please help me with this question'
```

"`.`" in regex matches any character. So " `.` " matches any character surrounded by spaces. You could also use "`\s.\s`" to match any character surrounded by any whitespace.